# Calculate new 3D camera position from azimtuh and elevation - Helix Toolkit

Tags: c#, 3d, helix-3d-toolkit

I do have my cameras LookDirection: -4,-2,-16
The camera's Position is the inverse of the LookDirection: 4,2,16

This represents a certain azimuth and elevation I guess.

Now, I would like to change my camera that my new azimuth is the old azimuth + 90°. Meaning I just see it lateral instead of frontal.

How would I do that in helix toolkit?

Do I have to calculate the azimuth, elevation from my current position, add my wanted azimuth and elevation to it and calculate the new camera look direction?

What about the new UpDirection?

Is there a simple way to do this? How would I do it?